# android LinearLayout performance

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have these lint warnings in my layout

```
Nested weights are bad for performance (11 items)
data.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance
```

This is my layout:

[image]

My layout is to show data. This data is almost shown as a table but some "rows" have to 3 or 4 `TextViews` and other's have 6 or 7. Since I want some of these `TextViews` to have the exact same width I've created all of those `LinearLayout` and use `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` to achieve what I want.

Since I cannot remove some of the views (they are all needed to show my data) what can I do to increase performance of my layout?

I've tried to use `RelativeLayout` but with that I can't use `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight`.

Thanks.

Favolas

**EDIT**

Sorry. Didn't understand that the XML was so important.

Here is the HUGE code:

http://pastebin.com/0mehGx2z

Some more explanations.

I have a database with one table with almost 50 columns.

I make a query to the database and this query returns a Cursor. The result is shown on a `ListView`. User selects one of these results and is then "send" to this layout were the data is shown on all of those fields

Comment: The xml of your layout would be MUCH easier for us to read and analyze. Can you please post it, instead of the tree structure?

Comment: Use adapters where possible to load the necessary views that are on screen. This improves performance. @prolink007, it would be huge..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are essentially trying to recreate what ListView already does. You definitely want to use ListView or GridView as they are designed and optimized for this task. Using a custom Adapter you can display your custom layouts. Additionally. I think I remember reading that [RelativeLayout is faster than LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Revise). Likely because it does not have to work so hard to determine the placement of child views. Just something else to consider.

The Google [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) shows how to dynamically load a ListView using a Loader. If you already have the data then you could easily strip out the Loader functionality.

```
public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data._ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

    // This is the select criteria
    static final String SELECTION = "((" + 
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

        // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        root.addView(progressBar);

        // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
        String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1}; // The TextView in simple_list_item_1

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    // Called when a new Loader needs to be created
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data unavailable
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something when a list item is clicked
    }
}
```